# "show dbs" command only showing local database but not newly created ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I started working with mongodb yesterday and can't seem to generate a database on the console.  Every time I do the

```
use exampledb
switched to db exampledb
```

but for some reason I still generate only my locals..?

```
show dbs
local  0.078GB
```

I created a folder called /data/db in my root directory (following the tutorial) so I'm not sure what I am missing... help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You are not missing anything. `exampledb` will be shown (using `show dbs`) only when you insert atleast one document in it. You can add collections manually if you want using `db.createCollection()`.

Comment: thank you I just found a link http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-create-database-or-collection-in-mongodb/ which basically said the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Your database need to have atleast one document inside. First we need to add atleast one document into the selected database.

Example:

```
db.mycollection.insert({"name":"Max"})
```

where `db` is the general term not the name of the database and `mycollection` is the name of your collection, inside the insert give as key value pairs)

After that you can see your database.

Answer (score 0):

Insert one Document and the "**show dbs**" command will display your database